# Puzzling Issue In Hitting HTTP Endpoint - Code Seems Correct However Getting 'Bad Request' Response

Tags: vb.net, http, system.net.httpwebrequest

Hi there I have been struggling to get what on the face of it appears a relatively simple call to an external API.  As far as I can make out the code should work, but responds with 'Bad Request'  here is the function that makes the call to the Login endpoint of the API:

```
 Public Async Function GetToken(ByVal wsInstance As Integer) As Task(Of String)

      Dim data As String = "{""password"":""" & _webServices(wsInstance).Pwd & """,""username"":""" & _webServices(wsInstance).Login & """}"

      Dim requestMsg As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _clients(wsInstance).BaseAddress)
      requestMsg.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*")
      requestMsg.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
      requestMsg.Content = New StringContent(data, Text.UTF8Encoding.Default, "application/json")
      Dim response As HttpResponseMessage

      response = _clients(wsInstance).SendAsync(requestMsg).Result
      If (response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
           return response.Content.ToString
      ElseIf (response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) Then
           Throw New BadHTTPRequestException("Bad HTTP Request With content: " & requestMsg.Content.ToString)
      End If

 End Function
```

The string variable 'data' contains the correct credentials (username and pwd obscured):

```
 {"password":"########","username":"####.#######@##############.co.uk"}
```

Which on inspection are correct for the account defined on the destination system.

The baseaddress in this instance is the full url for the endpoint.

Quite possible that I am missing something fundamental here but for the life of me I can't see what it is.

Kind Regards
Paul J

Comment: Honestly, "Bad Request" means just that, from experience the exact cause of that is different from site to site and often miss-reported by the server.  Best advice is get the request working in a tool Postman, then replicate it in code.  Alternately, contact service developers if you can and see if they can share any info on what's making your request bad